# Convert datetime printed by Django, to a different datetime format

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, formatting

My web application works with datetime(s) as timestamps, which according to Django's error messages need to be in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]`.

I display these timestimes on multiple occasions on the web application, where they're displayed in the following format: `12. June 2017 10:17`.

Now, the user is able to choose and submit the displayed timezones, which are then processed by the server. The server then error's because the format isn't correct.

How do I convert the format printed by Django on the web app (`12. Juni 2017 10:17`) to the format, required by Django for further processing (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]`)?

*edit:* Currently trying to create a datetime object of the received data, then convert it to the required format.

```
parsed_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST['timestamp'], "%y/%m/%d %B")
```

Which results in the following error:

```
time data '12. June 2017 10:17' does not match format '%y/%m/%d %B'
```

Comment: I am unsuccessfully trying to create a datetime object, with the information given by the client (`12. June 2017 10:17`), to then process the datetime in a custom format, using something like +`%y/%m/%d %B`

Comment: Include the code in your question

Comment: @JackEvans I've edited the question

Comment: strptime tries to parse the input data with the format string. Your input has the format '%d. %B %Y %H:%M'

Comment: Err... Are those values (" the format printed by Django on the web app") coming from Django itself ??? I mean, are those datetimes in the context passed from the view to the templte ? If yes, you shouldn't have to "try and convert" anything.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The values are displayed on the web app, from the view, for example `{{ db_entry.timestamp }}`. The user can choose the displayed timestamp, which is then used to query it in the database - for which the wrong format is posted.

Comment: Then why don't you use a distinct value (with the right representation) for the selection ? Are those links or widgets in a form ? In both cases the displayed value (link text or widget label) doesn't have to be the one used for either the link's url or the widget's value.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that makes much more sense. I need another coffee. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `"%y/%m/%d %B"` doesn't match the pattern `'12. June 2017 10:17'`

You can try using the following to parse the date correctly:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse

>>> parse('12. June 2017 10:17')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 10, 17)
```

Or with:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> datetime.strptime('12. June 2017 10:17', '%d. %B %Y %I:%M')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 10, 17)
```

You can work out what percentage values to use from this useful table in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it expects the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]` so the Valid values are:

```
2017-09-04 06:00
2017-09-04 06:00:00
2017-09-04 06:00:00.000000

# w/ optional TZ as timezone. 
2017-09-04 06:00Z # utc
2017-09-04 06:00:00+0800
2017-09-04 06:00:00.000000-08:00
```

This should do the trick:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('12. June 2017 10:17', '%d. %B %Y %H:%M')
print(d) # or print(str(d)) if you want it as a string
```

output:

```
2017-06-12 10:17:00
```

which is in the valid accepted format `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ])`

Answer (score 1):

(12. Juni 2017 10:17) is in Pseudocode:

`day`. `month in locale full name` `year with century` `hour`:`minute`

To convert this into a datetime object with [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) use:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(your_input, '%d. %B %Y %H:%M')
```

to convert back, use the equivalent `strftime`, with your format string.